# How to limit space used during query?

Tags: amazon-redshift

We're handling a ton of data for one vendor on a Redshift instance, and require a sequence of queries to categorize deidentified credit card transactions.  We have total Redshift storage of 15tb, and the static data takes up about half that.  Some queries that include several joins blow up and eat up all the space while executing, but only sometimes.  The ones that blow up typically have a fraction of the rows of other queries that have identical structure.

We figure the optimizer is making some bad decisions, but the query plan is different each time the blow-up-queries run.  When the same queries don't blow up, they complete in under a minute with now issues.  Same data.

The question here is, are there hints or settings we can use to force the optimizer to make certain decisions?  Or tips on how to organize our data better?

One error that has popped up states "Distributed a large number of rows across the network", if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a query that is “fat in the middle”.  This means that the query is “generating” new intermediate data during execution.  Cross joins can fall into this category but being “fat in the middle” can be created in a multitude of ways.

I’ve worked with many clients on similar issues and I suspect that the query and possibly the data organization will need to change to address this.  This said you will need to post the query and the explain plan to really get some insight from the community on what is happening.  The large amount of data be redistributed is not good but addressing the data size first is the right way to go.